# How can i set config.node in webpack encore

Tags: symfony, webpack, symfony4, splunk, webpack-encore

I'm using Symfony 4 with webpack encore.
I installed the splunk-sdk via npm install splunk-sdk.
now encore dev --watch throw this error

```
Running webpack ...


webpack is watching the files…

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors                                                                                                                                      7:04:33

This dependency was not found:

* fs in ./node_modules/request/lib/har.js, ./node_modules/splunk-sdk/lib/utils.js

To install it, you can run: npm install --save fs
```

I install fs, but the same error remains.

I read to insert folowing config in my webpack.config.js

```
config.node = {
        fs: 'empty'
    };
```

How can i do this with Encore?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue. You can refer to the webpack encore config advanced page :
[Webpack encore advanced config](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/frontend/encore/advanced-config.html?fbclid=IwAR2KkYnIZ3MbxAjV_yn6EzdvHmmn1hsSKoKM3LF3u9ALTNOmjK5talpQDTU)

At the end of your webpack config file, you can export the config with the function *getWebpackConfig()*, as following:

```
var config = Encore.getWebpackConfig();

config.node = {
  fs: 'empty',
};

module.exports = config;
```

If there already is a node configuration, it will be overridden. You can improve the code if necessary.